# Google datastore emulator web console

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm running a local stand-alone datastore emulator using the `gcloud` tool:

```
$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start
```

It works fine, but I'm missing the integrated `/_ah/admin` page the old appengine dev server offers. Is there something comparable for this emulator? A stand-alone project that just acts like a phpmyadmin, or a trick to reuse the appengine dev server's GUI; I'm fine with either.

Comment: Hey we wrote https://github.com/streamrail/dsui at Streamrail. This is a very basic UI for datastore emulator (read only) It also includes a search by Id and Name properties due to the way we define models. So, it might not fit everyone's needs perfectly, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: To use /_ah/admin, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897628/753632

Comment: @Johann see https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-datastore/issues/148#issuecomment-1089906973 as for why this apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Currently there is no GUI available to view/manage the data created through the Emulator. There is an open enhancement request for this at - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/148.

Comment: Maybe in 2017 you couldn't, but you can now:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897628/753632

Comment: @Johann see https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-datastore/issues/148#issuecomment-1089906973 as for why this apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try Google Cloud GUI written by Gabriel Axel at https://github.com/GabiAxel/google-cloud-gui. It works pretty well.