# Cannot view data from GCP Datastore (Firestore) in browser when using emulator

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am using Google's Datastore (which is Firestore's support for the GCP) and the emulator to handle storage locally. Everything works fine as far as storing data. But there does not appear to be any way of actually viewing the data in the browser. I have a feeling that this is not yet implemented because the emulator is still in beta. Has anyone been able to view data in their browser? It should be stressed that this is the emulator provided by the Google Cloud Platform SDK and not the one that Firebase uses for its products. The emulator is started with:

> gcloud beta emulators datastore start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **As of January 2022**

## Debugging

### Setting up Firebase Datastore Emulator (FDE)

The Firebase Datastore Emulator (FDE) emulates the Google Datastore in App Engine. This is meant to run on Java 8 platforms. When correctly setup, any Datastore operations are done locally and stored to a file called **local_db.bin**.

The documentation for using the Firebase Datastore Emulator can be found at:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

It should be noted that this documentaton contains errors and is missing some important settings. To use Firebase Datastore Emulator, install the emulator by running the following command from a terminal:

```
gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator
```

Start the emulator in a terminal:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=fbdatastore --host-port=localhost:8100
```

The official documentation does not indicate to use the `--host-port` flag. If you leave this flag out, a random port will be selected. But experience has shown that letting the port be randomly selected can result in exceptions generated by the client library used to access the local datastore - even when the port is correctly set in the environment variables.

The `--data-dir` flag indicates the directory where the local database file is stored. Here, it is specified as `fbdatastore` but you can use any folder located anywhere. You should make sure that the folder already exists before you start the emulator. In the example shown here, no path is included. This means that when you start the emulator, the directory specified by `--data-dir` should be in the same folder where you are launching the emulator.

The emulator will only create the local_db.bin file when you initially write data to it. If you don't write any data, it will not be created. Even it isn't created, the client APIs will still work correctly when reading from it, typically returning null values for any entities that you attempt to access. No exception will be thrown if the database file does not exist.

If the `--data-dir` is set to `fbdatastore` as used here, the **local_db.bin** file will be created under:

```
fbdatastore/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin
```

After the emulator has started, you can verify that it is running but opening a browser window and navigating to the url:

```
http://localhost:8100
```

This will only display the text "ok".

Before you can start debugging the app, several environment variables need to be set. You need to open a new terminal window and execute the following commands to set several variables:

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET=[project-id]
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8100
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8100/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8100
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=[project-id]
export DATASTORE_USE_PROJECT_ID_AS_APP_ID=true
```

The client libraries for the Datastore expect the app id to be used. But it was found that using only the app id didn't work. The environment variable `DATASTORE_USE_PROJECT_ID_AS_APP_ID` needs to be set as well. This is not specified in the documentation.

It should be noted that the official docs show the following:

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET=my-project-id
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=::1:8432
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=::1:8432/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://::1:8432
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id
```

For MacOS, this is wrong. The variables with values set to `::1` is wrong. Using this will cause exceptions and probably prevent the emulator from even loading. The `::1` needs to be replaced with `localhost`, as shown above.

You can just copy the 6 lines shown above and paste them into a terminal and hit Enter. But it is easier to just place these into a bash file and execute it. These need to be set before the local development server is started. The following bash file will set the environment variables and then start the development server:

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET=[project-id]
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8100
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8100/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8100
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=[project-id]
export DATASTORE_USE_PROJECT_ID_AS_APP_ID=true
java_dev_appserver.sh --address=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --disable_update_check --jvm_flag=-Xdebug --jvm_flag=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 build/exploded-website
```

Replace [project-id] with the project id shown in your Googel Cloud Platform console (don't include the square brackets).

The address parameter for java_dev_appserver.sh is set here to 8000. You will need to set this in your IDE. Also, the port for java_dev_appserver.sh is set to 8080. You can set this to whatever works on your system and doesn't conflict with any existing ports used elsewhere. The last parameter for java_dev_appserver.sh is the location of your war files, which is the compiled app. Here, it is located at build/web-site. Replace this with the location of your own build files.

To view the datastore locally in your browser, navigate to:

http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore

Details on the command parameters used to start the emulator can be found at:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start

Comment: This seems to rely on the Java Dev Appserver, which only works for legacy AppServer apps written in Java. This does not cover apps written in another language (e.g. Python) nor apps for non-legacy runtimes (which do not use the dev_appserver). Am I correct?

Comment: This answer is so amazingly thorough. Makes me wonder why the docs don't explain all of this.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I wonder if running the equivalent servers for each language (e.g., `dev_appserver.py`) would expose a similar browser endpoint at `/_ah/admin/datastore`

Comment: I'm using a maven launch in eclipse to start the server. The  java_dev_appserver.sh  line you provide didn't do anything.
In a maven launch I would presumably have to set environment variables for java_dev_appserver.sh ?
Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand what you want to do is to add data in the Datastore emulator running on your console and be able to see this data in the UI right?

Vieweing the data in the UI actually incurs in expenses for you because Datastore have to query the data to be able to display it on the UI.

I can still recommend you to create a [Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) if you want to be able to see the entries form the Datastore emulator for free in the UI

Comment: I'm only interested in viewing data in the browser when stored locally. This should not be a feature request. It existed in the previous version.