# local_db.bin not created. Data is stored in online Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, dev-appserver

I am using the local GAE development server `java_dev_appserver` to debug my app. When using Datastore, it is suppose to store the data in a file called `local_db.bin` but instead it is storing the data in the Datastore of GAE online.

I'm not using a service account locally to cause the redirect, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Has something changed in either the `java_dev_appserver` or the client libraries that cause the data to be stored online?

Interestingly, the console messages from `java_dev_appserver` indicate that `local_db.bin` will be created. But it never gets created and data goes straight to the online storage.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the documentation for using the local development server to host the datastore is outdated:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server

The current way of using a local datastore is by using the Datastore Emulator:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

However, even the newer documentation has errors and omissions. For a detailed description on how to properly set up a local datastore, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897628/753632